# how to migrate data from old docker gitlab container to new container

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a very old docker gitlab that was running fine until i tried to upgrade and the rest is history. It never worked.

So now my plans are to setup a new container on a new server and then just copy over the git repo data from the old docker host to the new docker host running the new container

here are the volumes i exposed to the host for both the old and new containers

```
--volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab 
--volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
--volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

what i have tried it check the gitlab data directories to see where the git repos are stored on the old docker host but i cant find anything as it shows empty

```
root@gitlab:~# ls -lha /srv/gitlab/data/git-data/repositories/
total 48K
drwxrws---  9 998  998 4.0K Aug  9  2021 .
drwx------  3 998 root 4.0K Jun  8  2016 ..
drwxrwx---  2 998  998  12K Oct 24  2020 devops
drwxr-sr-x  3 998  998 4.0K Aug  1  2021 +gitaly
-rw-------  1 998  998   64 Jun 18  2020 .gitaly-metadata
drwxr-s--- 91 998  998 4.0K Oct 24  2020 @hashed
drwxr-s---  3 998  998 4.0K Oct 25  2020 @snippets




root@gitlab:~# ls -lha /srv/gitlab/data/git-data/repositories/devops/
total 16K
drwxrwx--- 2 998 998  12K Oct 24  2020 .
drwxrws--- 9 998 998 4.0K Aug  9  2021 ..
```

so anyone know where the git repo data are stored on a docker host running gitlab?

Comment: Repositories are in the @hashed directory : https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/repository_storage_types.html

Comment: so i just need to copy over that directory? how will the repos get mapped to the hashed files? on the new server

Comment: you can try to backup and restore on the new instance, but the best thing should be upgrading following all migrations paths..

Comment: i have wasted weeks/months with upgrading, it is time wasting and is not working. I have to climb from version 10 to 15 by the way. my question is about migrating over just repo data